# Creating an instance from a class name

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to create an instance of a class at run time. The classes I'm trying to create all inherit from a base class, ConfigMgrObj, and are named `ConfigMgr_xxxxxx` e.g. `ConfigMgr_Collection`. They all take a special object that I'm calling oController and a string as arguments.

This is the line I'm using to do it, where ClassToGet is a string that contains the name of the class e.g. `ConfigMgr_Collection`.

```
object oNewObject = System.Activator.CreateInstance(null, "StackOverflowNamespace." + ClassToGet, new object[] { oController, ClassToGet });
```

This throws a TypeLoadException exception. What's up with it?

Comment: Can you expand your question, is the assembly that contains the type loaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are the types you're trying to instantiate actually declared within the same assembly? Passing null as the first parameter is telling Activator that the types live in the current assembly.

Comment: Dammit, that's it. I forgot I was doing this in the GUI, with all my stuff in the same namespace but a different assembly. Have an accepted answer to mitigate my stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it did not find the the class named `"StackOverflowNamespace."+ClassToGet` in the current assembly.