# How to get qualifiers for a class

Tags: vb.net, class

I have the following code to create an instance of one of my classes based on the class name.

```
'Get a System.Type corresponding to the name of the parent class  
Dim tt As Type = Type.GetType(item.ParentClass)
'Create an instance of the specified type using the types default constructor
Dim theObject As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(tt)
```

This works fine if I have the full class as in `MainClassName.Namespace.ClassName`
But if I try to do this with just `ClassName`,  `tt` equals to nothing.

Is there a way to use `ClassName` and get the fully qualified name as in `MainClassName.Namespace.ClassName`

Comment: Okay, where's `ClassName` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to use `ClassName` and get the fully qualified name as in `MainClassName.Namespace.ClassName`

No. This cannot logically work. Consider the following case: you have two classes, `Foo.X` and `Bar.X`. Just specifying `X` is therefore ambiguous. Indeed that’s the motivation behind namespaces and fully qualified names in the first place.

Even if it were possible (for instance by returning a *list* of candidate types) this would be impractical since it would require the runtime to walk through the whole list of classes that are loaded by all referenced assemblies. This can be a *huge* number, even with just the basic framework loaded. `GetType` would be prohibitively inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Type.AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx), like this:

```
'part 1 of your code - store class name in a universal format
Dim className As String = GetType(item.ParentClass).AssemblyQualifiedName

'part 2 of your code - use a previously stored class name to create instance
Dim tt As Type = Type.GetType(className)
Dim theObject As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(tt)
```

Credit goes to this [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5282678/897326).

Comment: This actually returns system.string as the full name. The item.parentclass is a string value with the class name

Comment: @DanRowe: I corrected my answer after checking the syntax with VS 2010. Does it make more sense now? `.AssemblyQualifiedName` should return a `String`, but it would take care of namespacing for you, and also the version.

Comment: `GetType(var)` and `Type.GetType(typename)` return the same thing. Your code is redundant.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: No it's not, there a slight difference, which it makes it a compilation error - I just came back from VS, remember. :)

Comment: @Neolisk See amended comment. They’re not the *same* but they give equivalent results for appropriate input. They don’t solve OP’s problem. `Type.GetType(x.AssemblyQualifiedName)` will always give you `x`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: OP's problem is not clear to me then. I was under the impression he needs to store a string name of class and he does not want to store it as just the class name, because it would not work in a `CreateInstance`.

Comment: @Neolisk Indeed that’s what OP wants but your code doesn’t work like that. In fact, there’s another problem: `GetType` accepts a *type*, not a string variable, as its argument.

Comment: I see what you corrected but it is still not making a difference. If I type this type.gettype(Type.GetType("ABC.Merchants.ApplicationBusinessProfile").FullName) it works fine but if I do this type.gettype(Type.GetType("ApplicationBusinessProfile").FullName) it is returned as nothing.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: [Type.GetType accepts a String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx). That's what I meant by them being different.

Comment: @DanRowe: And how do you expect the program to figure out what `ApplicationBusinessProfile` means?

Comment: @Neolisk I wasn’t talking about `Type.GetType`, I was talking about “part 1” of your code. But part 2 also has a logic error, noted earlier (= if you already have the type, derived by part 1, then using `AssemblyFullName` and `Type.GetType` is a pure redundancy).

Comment: well sir that is why I was asking. If i use a string value with the entire name it works I thought there may be a way to get the fully qualified path. I guess than Konrad is correct

Comment: @DanRowe: The thing is you can use an entire name, but you don't have to hard code it. So you can create your own internal dictionary of types, if it makes your life more simple, then use that down the road. `Key` = short type name, `Value` = long type name.